# Unable to insert a piece of data into the hudi table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
spark-sql> insert into hudi_mor_tbl select 1, 'a1', 20, 1000;
Error in query: org.apache.hudi.EmptyRelation@7c523bdd does not allow insertion.;
'InsertIntoStatement Relation[_hoodie_commit_time#44,_hoodie_commit_seqno#45,_hoodie_record_key#46,_hoodie_partition_path#47,_hoodie_file_name#48,id#49,name#50,price#51,ts#52L] org.apache.hudi.EmptyRelation@7c523bdd, false, false
+- Project [1 AS 1#125, a1 AS a1#126, 20 AS 20#127, 1000 AS 1000#128]
   +- OneRowRelation

spark-sql> 
enter image description here
```

Unable to insert a piece of data into the hudi table

How do I insert data into the hudi table